# How can i retrieve google page speed score using curl

Tags: php, google-app-engine, curl, google-api

Upon reading google page speed api developer's guide
i would like to retrieve page speed score using curl or whatever can retrieve it from the output

Here should be the link i'm going to use (i only needs score `"score": 97` cause i will store it in database)

```
https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v1/runPagespeed?url=http://www.my_site.com&key={MY API KEY}
```

it will gives the following results

```
{
 "kind": "pagespeedonline#result",
 "request": {
  "url": "http://www.my___site.com"
 },
 "id": "http://www.my___site.com/",
 "responseCode": 404,
 "title": "404 Error - Page Not Found",
 "score": 97,
 "pageStats": {
  "numberResources": 19,
  "numberHosts": 11,
  "totalRequestBytes": "4982",
  "numberStaticResources": 10,
  "htmlResponseBytes": "67960",
  "cssResponseBytes": "11318",
  "imageResponseBytes": "20824",
  "javascriptResponseBytes": "200855",
  "otherResponseBytes": "52076",
  "numberJsResources": 6,
  "numberCssResources": 2
 },
 "formattedResults": {
  "locale": "en_US",
  "ruleResults": {
   "AvoidLandingPageRedirects": {
    "localizedRuleName": "Avoid landing page redirects",
    "ruleScore": 100,
    "ruleImpact": 0.0,
    "urlBlocks": [
     {
      "header": {
       "format": "Your page has no redirects. Learn more about avoiding landing page redirects.",
       "args": [
        {
         "type": "HYPERLINK",
         "value": "https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/AvoidRedirects"
        }
       ]
      }
     }
    ]
   },
   "EnableGzipCompression": {
    "localizedRuleName": "Enable compression",
    "ruleScore": 100,
    "ruleImpact": 0.0,
    "urlBlocks": [
     {
      "header": {
       "format": "You have compression enabled. Learn more about enabling compression.",
       "args": [
        {
         "type": "HYPERLINK",
         "value": "https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/EnableCompression"
        }
       ]
      }
     }
    ]
   },
   "LeverageBrowserCaching": {
    "localizedRuleName": "Leverage browser caching",
    "ruleScore": 90,
    "ruleImpact": 0.49702380952380953,
    "urlBlocks": [
     {
      "header": {
       "format": "Setting an expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers for static resources instructs the browser to load previously downloaded resources from local disk rather than over the network."
      }
     },
     {
      "header": {
       "format": "Leverage browser caching for the following cacheable resources:",
       "args": [
        {
         "type": "HYPERLINK",
         "value": "https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/LeverageBrowserCaching"
        }
       ]
      },
      "urls": [
       {
        "result": {
         "format": "$1 ($2)",
         "args": [
          {
           "type": "URL",
           "value": "http://www.google.com/adsense/domains/caf.js"
          },
          {
           "type": "DURATION",
           "value": "60 minutes"
          }
         ]
        }
       }
      ]
     }
    ]
   },
   "MainResourceServerResponseTime": {
    "localizedRuleName": "Reduce server response time",
    "ruleScore": 100,
    "ruleImpact": 0.0,
    "urlBlocks": [
     {
      "header": {
       "format": "Your server responded quickly. Learn more about server response time optimization.",
       "args": [
        {
         "type": "HYPERLINK",
         "value": "https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/Server"
        }
       ]
      }
     }
    ]
   },
   "MinifyCss": {
    "localizedRuleName": "Minify CSS",
    "ruleScore": 100,
    "ruleImpact": 0.0,
    "urlBlocks": [
     {
      "header": {
       "format": "Your CSS is minified. Learn more about minifying CSS.",
       "args": [
        {
         "type": "HYPERLINK",
         "value": "https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/MinifyResources"
        }
       ]
      }
     }
    ]
   },
   "MinifyHTML": {
    "localizedRuleName": "Minify HTML",
    "ruleScore": 94,
    "ruleImpact": 0.2277,
    "urlBlocks": [
     {
      "header": {
       "format": "Compacting HTML code, including any inline JavaScript and CSS contained in it, can save many bytes of data and speed up download and parse times."
      }
     },
     {
      "header": {
       "format": "Minify HTML for the following resources to reduce their size by $2 ($3 reduction).",
       "args": [
        {
         "type": "HYPERLINK",
         "value": "https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/MinifyResources"
        },
        {
         "type": "BYTES",
         "value": "2.1KiB"
        },
        {
         "type": "PERCENTAGE",
         "value": "9%"
        }
       ]
      },
      "urls": [
       {
        "result": {
         "format": "Minifying $1 could save $2 ($3 reduction) after compression.",
         "args": [
          {
           "type": "URL",
           "value": "http://dsnextgen.com/?domainname=www.my___site.com&a_id=101686&session_token=undefined"
          },
          {
           "type": "BYTES",
           "value": "2.1KiB"
          },
          {
           "type": "PERCENTAGE",
           "value": "9%"
          }
         ]
        }
       }
      ]
     }
    ]
   },
   "MinifyJavaScript": {
    "localizedRuleName": "Minify JavaScript",
    "ruleScore": 100,
    "ruleImpact": 0.0,
    "urlBlocks": [
     {
      "header": {
       "format": "Your JavaScript content is minified. Learn more about minifying JavaScript.",
       "args": [
        {
         "type": "HYPERLINK",
         "value": "https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/MinifyResources"
        }
       ]
      }
     }
    ]
   },
   "MinimizeRenderBlockingResources": {
    "localizedRuleName": "Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content",
    "ruleScore": 100,
    "ruleImpact": 2.0,
    "urlBlocks": [
     {
      "header": {
       "format": "Your page has $1 blocking script resources. This causes a delay in rendering your page.",
       "args": [
        {
         "type": "INT_LITERAL",
         "value": "2"
        }
       ]
      }
     },
     {
      "header": {
       "format": "None of the above-the-fold content on your page could be rendered without waiting for the following resources to load. Try to defer or asynchronously load blocking resources, or inline the critical portions of those resources directly in the HTML."
      }
     },
     {
      "header": {
       "format": "Remove render-blocking JavaScript:",
       "args": [
        {
         "type": "HYPERLINK",
         "value": "https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS"
        }
       ]
      },
      "urls": [
       {
        "result": {
         "format": "$1",
         "args": [
          {
           "type": "URL",
           "value": "http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/apps/domainpark/show_afd_ads.js"
          }
         ]
        }
       },
       {
        "result": {
         "format": "$1",
         "args": [
          {
           "type": "URL",
           "value": "http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/apps/domainpark/domainpark.cgi?callback=_google_json_callback&output=js&client=ca-dp-oversee_ncd&domain_name=www.my___site.com&st=create&s=www.my___site.com&dt=1381663474340&u_tz=-420&u_his=1&u_h=768&u_w=1024&frm=0"
          }
         ]
        }
       }
      ]
     }
    ]
   },
   "OptimizeImages": {
    "localizedRuleName": "Optimize images",
    "ruleScore": 100,
    "ruleImpact": 0.0,
    "urlBlocks": [
     {
      "header": {
       "format": "Your images are optimized. Learn more about optimizing images.",
       "args": [
        {
         "type": "HYPERLINK",
         "value": "https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeImages"
        }
       ]
      }
     }
    ]
   },
   "PrioritizeVisibleContent": {
    "localizedRuleName": "Prioritize visible content",
    "ruleScore": 100,
    "ruleImpact": 0.0,
    "urlBlocks": [
     {
      "header": {
       "format": "You have the above-the-fold content properly prioritized. Learn more about prioritizing visible content.",
       "args": [
        {
         "type": "HYPERLINK",
         "value": "https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/PrioritizeVisibleContent"
        }
       ]
      }
     }
    ]
   }
  }
 },
 "version": {
  "major": 1,
  "minor": 14
 }
}
```

thanks for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in JSON, so you need to `json_decode` it first.

```
$json = json_decode($data);
echo $json->score;
```